# About Calculating Basic Probability

Tags: probability

- There are a total of $100,000$ stuffed animals.
- $1$ in $200$ in defected.
- If the sample size is $20$, what is the probability that it will have a defected piece in it?

If we break $100,000$ into several different sets of $200$, we will have $500$ sets. Per set of $200$:

- $P(\text{defected}) = 1/200 = 0.005\%$ (which is the same as $500/100000$).
- $P(\text{not defected}) = 1-0.005 = 0.995\%$.

From a sample of $20$, $P(20 \text{ are good}) = 0.995^{20} = 0.90\%$, so if this is right there is $90\%$ chance that the sample of $20$ is good and there is $10\%$ chance that there is a defected piece in it?

Comment: Please show your own ideas and thoughts.

Comment: if we break 100,000 into several different sets of 200, we will have 500 sets.

per set of 200:
-P(defected) = 1/200 = 0.005% (which is the same as 500/100000)
-P(not defected) = 1-0.005 = 0.995&

-from a sample of 20, P(20 are good) = 0.995^20 = 0.90% , so if this is right there is 90% chance that the sample of 20 is good and there is 10% chance that there is a defected piece in it?

Comment: The numbers are big enough for this to be a good approximation. But see the answer below for the correct way to compute the exact probability.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The probability of picking up 3 stuffed animals and discovering that none of them are defected is  $$99800/100000 \times 99799/99999 \times 99798/99998$$ since we can see that the probability of randomly picking one stuffed animal and discovering that it is defected is $\frac{200}{100000}$ and the probability that it is not defected is $\frac{100000-200}{100000 }$.